# Perl concept dynamic reference to an array

Tags: arrays, perl, dynamic, reference

I am trying to understand in Perl the difference between a normal array reference
\@array and [@array].

Covered in the following article, http://perl-begin.org/tutorials/perl-for-newbies/part2/, it says
"An array surrounded by square brackets ([ @array ]) returns a dynamic reference to an array. This reference does not affect other values directly, which is why it is called dynamic. "
The last sentence above where it says the reference does not affect other values directly isn't clear to me, what other values are they refering to?  A few websites copied and paste the same explanation.  Can someone provide a better explanation that highlight the differences?

Here is an example they provided:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub vector_sum
{
    my $v1_ref = shift;
    my $v2_ref = shift;

    my @ret;

    my @v1 = @{$v1_ref};
    my @v2 = @{$v2_ref};

    if (scalar(@v1) != scalar(@v2))
    {
        return undef;
    }
    for(my $i=0;$i<scalar(@v1);$i++)
    {
        push @ret, ($v1[$i] + $v2[$i]);
    }

    return [ @ret ];
}

my $ret = vector_sum(
    [ 5, 9, 24, 30 ],
    [ 8, 2, 10, 20 ]
);

print join(", ", @{$ret}), "\n";
```

However, in the example given above, if I change the return [ @ret ]; to \@ret, the program returns the same result, so I am not sure how this serves as an example to illustrate dynamic reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I question that tutorial.  When the perl docs use the term "dynamic", they are almost always referring to variable scope.  You won't find consideration of a "dynamic arrayref" in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) nor [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

That said:

```
\@array   # reference to @array
[@array]  # reference to an unnamed *copy* of @array
```

Consider what happens when we take a reference to, or a reference to a copy of, @ARGV:

```
$ perl -E '$a = \@ARGV; $a->[0] = "FOO"; say for @ARGV' blah blah
FOO
blah

$ perl -E '$a = [@ARGV]; $a->[0] = "FOO"; say for @ARGV' blah blah
blah
blah
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to understand in Perl the difference between a normal array reference `\@array` and `[@array]`.

They're both exactly the same kind of references; they just produce references to different arrays.

```
[ ... ]
```

is basically the same thing as

```
do { my @anon = (...); \@anon }
```

So

```
my @abc = qw( a b c );
my $ref1 = \@abc;
my $ref2 = [ @abc ];
say @$ref1, @$ref2;  # abcabc
@abc = qw( d e f );
say @$ref1, @$ref2;  # defabc
```

---

> "This reference does not affect other values directly, which is why it is called dynamic. "

It's not called "dynamic", and that's not a definition of dynamic I've ever encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple illustration:

```
my @array = (2, 3, 5, 6);
my $ref = \@array;
my $dynamic_ref = [@array];

print q{$array[1] = }, $array[1], "\n";
print q{$ref->[1] = }, $ref->[1], "\n";
print q{$dynamic_ref->[1] = }, $dynamic_ref->[1], "\n";

$array[1] = 10;
print "=" x 20, "\n";

print q{$array[1] = }, $array[1], "\n";
print q{$ref->[1] = }, $ref->[1], "\n";
print q{$dynamic_ref->[1] = }, $dynamic_ref->[1], "\n";
```

In other words you have a **reference to the copy** of original array and all changes to the original array doesn't affect this copy.